# AssemblyResolve event not hit

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have an app that depends on some assemblies stored in a subfolder. I'd like to get rid of the `app.config` file (and the `privatePath="MySubFolder"` within) and I don't want to install the assemblies into the GAC.

What I'm trying to do is to use the AssemblyResolve event to tell the app where to look for the assemblies. However, when I run the app I get a `FileNotFoundException` before the execution hits the AssemblyResolve handler. In fact I get that error before anything else happens. I placed a breakpoint on the entry point of the app and the exception comes before the very first line of code is executed.

This is the same with both .NET 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: hello sir pls come to chat

Answer (score 1):

You need to delay loading of the referenced assemblies by moving the code using them to another method. See this question for more details:
[When are referenced Assemblies loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785520/when-are-referenced-assemblies-loaded)

Comment: And preferably: explicitly mark the inner method as do-not-inline. Basically, anything to block the JIT for a moment ;p