# When is a .NET assembly unloaded?

Tags: .net, clr

We know that a .NET assembly is **loaded** at the last possible moment - when you enter a method that references a something in the foreign assembly.

When is an assembly **unloaded**? Is it when there are no longer any references to any classes/resources in the assembly? Is it never?

Imagine the class in the foreign assembly has a private static. The static is initialized when first needed. Presumably that static will no longer contain a value when the static variable is removed from memory.

When is an unreferenced static class removed from memory?

When is a .NET assembly unloaded?

## Bonus Reading

- [When are referenced Assemblies loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785520/when-are-referenced-assemblies-loaded)
- [Delay Loading .Net Assemblies](http://innovatian.com/2009/06/delay-loading-net-assemblies/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's only unloaded when the `AppDomain` that it's loaded into is unloaded, e.g. as part of a web app recycling.

Any classes within the assembly stay loaded while the assembly is loaded, so therefore they stick around until the `AppDomain` is unloaded too.