# Will my .NET program run without DLLs if I do not refer to anything in them?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I want to deploy a single set of compiled assemblies for my software.

The main program contains references to DLLs which are used only in some sites, not in others. Some will have a button to, say, run reports, which will use the DLLs, others *will not have* the button, so cannot run the code which uses the DLLs.

But do I need to distribute the DLLs on all systems OR only on systems where they will be used?

Are there any issues I need to consider?

Comment: It is technically possible, you however have to isolate every method that might call a method that might not be available, put a [MethodImpl] attribute on it so it won't be inlined and add an if() statement that avoids calling it.  The few seconds you save by not having to copy the DLLs is not matched well with the many hours you need to ensure that this is done correctly.  Skimping on testing arms a ticking time-bomb.

Comment: As in my code the code running the "optional" DLLs is already isolated and will always remain that way, this risk is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [When are referenced Assemblies loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785520/when-are-referenced-assemblies-loaded):

> When you enter a method that references a type in another assembly.

So as long as the code using those types can not be called, because the button whose click event calls that method is hidden, you can just omit those assemblies.

Comment: The above page references [Delay Loading .Net Assemblies](http://innovatian.com/2009/06/delay-loading-net-assemblies/) which I find very clear and helpful.

In summary it suggests your method does _not include_ both a conditional clause and a reference to the "optional" assembly, _but_ a conditional clause and a call to a separate method which references the "optional" assembly. 

As this is simple and relatively intuitive, it suits me well.